# convert null value in stringbuilder to "not available" string

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have edited existing code to do what I would like it to do for the most part. When there is data this works properly. However when MAXGUST and PRECIPITATION have null values I get errors. CITY and STATE will always have values. Is it possible to insert if/then statement in my StringBuilder?

```
if (obj.Properties().Any(x => x.Name == "CITY") && obj.Properties().Any(x => x.Name == "STATE"))
{
    var city1 = obj.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "CITY").Select(y => y.Value.Value<string>()).FirstOrDefault();
    var state1 = obj.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "STATE").Select(y => y.Value.Value<string>()).FirstOrDefault();
    var maxGust = obj.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "MAXGUST").Select(y => y.Value.Value<int>()).FirstOrDefault();
    var precip = obj.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "PRECIPITATION").Select(y => y.Value.Value<float>()).FirstOrDefault();

    this.Description =
            new StringBuilder().Append(city1).Append(", ").Append(state1)
            .Append("<br />").Append(maxGust).Append(" MPH Gust")
            .Append("<br />").Append(precip).Append(" in").ToString();

}
```

Comment: precip = precip ?? "your string"

Comment: Why not use `string.Format`? Why create a stringbuilder for this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Guffa I am getting a null value cannot be converted to a value type. I think the error is where is happening when I declare the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since maxGust`is of type`int`and`precip`is a`float`, **they can never be null**, instead you have to check them with the their default values (0, 0f)

like:

```
.Append(maxGust != default(int) ? maxGust.ToString() : " not available ")
```

and

```
.Append(precip != default(float) ? precip.ToString() : " not available ") 
        //or precip != 0f
```

Consider using `string.Format`, you really don't have to use `StringBuilder` for one time concentration.

Comment: Thank you I will try this out. Actually I have a few more int variables to concatenate.

Comment: @Andrew, still don't use `StringBuilder`, StringBuilder would really be useful in a situation where you are creating a string in multiple iterations.

Comment: I am getting error of "null value cannot be converted to a value type" in my application once I run it. I commented out all the stringbuilder code so it must be in my var statements for maxGust and precip.

Comment: You will need to use `int?` and `float?`, which supports nullable values, and then in comparison use `maxGust != null` ...

Answer (score 4):

<strike>you can use the `??` operator, which returns the right operand if the left operand is null.</strike>

```
.Append(maxGust ?? "not available")...
```

---

EDIT: the answer above won't work in your case, since `maxGust` is of type `int` and can never be null. So, with your current code, the question doesn't really make sense. If it's possible that `maxGust` doesn't have a value, it should be of type `int?` (which is the same as `Nullable<int>`), and the expression that assigns it should be modified to return null if there is no value.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error. "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int and string"

Comment: `maxGust` is of type `int`  and `precip` is a float, they can never be null, instead you have to check them with the their default values *(0, 0f)*

Comment: @Andrew, indeed it doesn't work with value types... but then, your requirement doesn't really make sense, if maxGust can't be null. Consider using nullable types instead

Comment: -1, Wrong answer. this will not work as `int` and `string` are different

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to chain all of those expressions together. Split them out and you can use normal conditionals:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
if (myVariable != null)
{
    sb.Append(myVariable);
}

...

this.Description = sb.ToString();
```